# Post form in JQuery and populate DIV - broken in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to create a form that posts data via jQuery and populates the return into the same DIV. This way the page does not refresh on post action.

```
<div id="add_value_form">

<form method="POST" action="#" onsubmit='return false'>
  <!-- input fields -->
  <input type="submit" value="Add" onclick='post_form("/add_value");'>
</form>

</div>
```

The JS function:

```
function post_form(url) {
  $.post(url, {'test':'test'}, function(data) {
    $("#add_value_form").empty().append(data); 
  }, "text");
}
```

This works perfectly in FF3, however it would only work randomly in IE6/7.

The server confirms that post requests are coming through from IE, yet it would get the post data only occasionally.

Curious, I decided to alert the data variable:

```
$.post(url, {'test':'test'}, function(data) {alert(data);}, "text");
```

Surely enough, FF3 would print out the return HTML every time, while IE6/7 would mostly print blanks, with an occasional HTML return. I was not able to find anything on this problem, so what am I doing wrong?

**Resolved:** I tracked this to an HTTP redirect I had in my request handling code. So the function handling the POST request would throw a redirect, and IE does not like it. I had a total mental constipation at the time, and I don't really need the redirect.

The weird part, of course, is that this works in FF, and IE would on occasion work as well, with the redirect in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that you don't have to use the form tag at all in this scenario.

```
<div id="add_value_form">
  <!-- input fields -->
  <input type="button" value="Add" onclick='post_form("/add_value");' />
</div>
```

**Edit**
As Paolo Bergantino said I would also avoid using the inline javascript.  So instead use:

```
<div id="add_value_form">
  <!-- input fields -->
  <input type="button" value="Add" class="formSubmitButton" />
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.formSubmitButton').click(function() {
      $.post('/add_value', {'test':'test'}, function(data) {
          $("#add_value_form").empty().append($(data));
      }, "text");
  });
});
```

**Update**  Since this is still causing a problem, I would perform some testing with the `$.ajax` method.  Also, I don't believe that POST calls would ever get cached, but just in case try setting the cached to false.  Another test, to make sure your not having a serialization issue, is to pass your data in already encoded.  And if your still having issues you can try to set your dataType to text

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/add_value',
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false,
  data: 'test=testValue',
  dataType: 'text',
  complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
    alert('completed');
  },
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('woops');
  }
});
```

Comment: Indeed, yet I still get the random behavior from IE :(

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to troubleshoot this with .ajax already, in fact. So far I get the obscure 'error' return, in both browsers, to my own endless joy, but this is very helpful.