# form.submit() to a specific DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to submit a form using Javascript and jQuery to specific div but I can't work out how to do it.

This code below works, submitting the form to the header of the current page.

```
    var form,
        chart = this,
        svg = chart.getSVG(chartOptions);

    // merge the options
    options = merge(chart.options.exporting, options);

    // create the form
    form = createElement('form', {
        method: 'post',
        action: options.url
    }, {
        display: NONE
    }, doc.body);

    // add the values
    each(['filename', 'type', 'width', 'svg'], function(name) {
        createElement('input', {
            type: HIDDEN,
            name: name,
            value: {
                filename: options.filename || 'chart',
                type: options.type,
                width: options.width,
                svg: svg
            }[name]
        }, null, form);
    });

    // submit
    form.submit();

    // clean up
    discardElement(form);
```

I have tried various options but nothing has worked. In simple terms I want to do this:

`$('#myDiv').form.submit();`

Or in other words, send the submit command to the div named `myDiv`.

Does anyone know how I would do this? Thanks.

Comment: `$('#myDiv form').submit();` maybe?

Comment: it's not that but thanks, another option eliminated.

Comment: You can't `submit` a `div`. You can only `submit` a `form`, and your own example has `form.submit()`, so it's not clear what the question is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post form in JQuery and populate DIV - broken in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717703/post-form-in-jquery-and-populate-div-broken-in-ie)

Comment: okay, to explain further. On the ready event of the document I want this form to be automatically submitted. The form params create a chart on a server and send back a PNG image. I am then using php to get the contents of the PNG and save it. Therefore this `form.submit` needs to run in the background, not to the header of the page, so I want to submit the form into a hidden div on the page where my php is located. Hope that makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the code given here:

[Post form in JQuery and populate DIV - broken in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717703/post-form-in-jquery-and-populate-div-broken-in-ie/717710#717710)

```
$.ajax({
  url: options.url,
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false,
  data: {
            filename: options.filename || 'chart',
            type: options.type,
            width: options.width,
            svg: svg
        },
  dataType: 'text',
  complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
    alert('completed');
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $("#myDiv").html(data);
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('woops');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the solution. It took me 8 hours to solve that one :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myDiv').click (function () {
$("form").submit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks but its not a click event. This event takes place as part of a load of stuff @ `$(document).ready`.